# Where do I change the height of a navigationBar for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

In my applicationDidFinishLaunching I set up a UINavigationController:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [[navController navigationBar] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,20.0)];
...
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to make the navigation controller's height 20px.  However, this is not working.  I would imagine setFrame must be the correct function but I am not calling it in the right place.  I realize that other questions on SO are similar to mine, but I think setting the navigationBar height should be possible if it responds to setFrame...right?

Also, anyone know the default height of the navigationBar?

Thanks!

Comment: put it in viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 5):

The default height of the navigation bar is 44px.

I am not sure you should be attempting to directly resize the navigation bar, the documentation certainly discourages it:

> When used in conjunction with a
>   navigation controller, there are only
>   a handful of direct customizations you
>   can make to the navigation bar.
>   Specifically, it is alright to modify
>   the barStyle, tintColor, and
>   translucent properties of this class,
>   but you must never directly change
>   UIView-level properties such as the
>   frame, bounds, alpha, or hidden
>   properties directly.

Depending on what you are trying to do it may be easier to place a new UIView over/below the navigation bar.

Comment: If my final objective is to make the navigation bar to 20px height, how can I move up the content view of navigation controller by 20px?

Comment: Perhaps you have to create your own and custom container navigation controller.

Answer (score 3):

Default height is 44 pixels for navigationbar.
If you want to change it, try adding a category to UINavigationBar and override setFrame: method.